# Преобразовать строку без разделителя в дату

Tags: java, парсер

С файла xls парсится начальная дата и конечная. В исходнике и списке она имеет вид 20120720.

Эти даты я поместил в два ArrayList и они имеют String формат.

Вопрос: какой паттерн или стандарт использовать для приведения данной строки к DateFormat?

Привожу код программы:

```
    ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))){
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            res.add(line);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<String> FirstDate = new ArrayList<>(res.size());
    List<String> LastDate = new ArrayList<>(res.size());
    res.remove(0); //удалить 1 элемент (название столбца)

    for(String item:res) {
        String[] splitted = item.split(",(?=([^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*$)");
        FirstDate.add(splitted[10]);
        LastDate.add(splitted[11]);
    }
```

Пробовал ввести такой формат и поменять тип данных в списке на DateFormat, но выдает ошибку java.text.ParseException

```
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        List<LocalDate> FirstDate = new ArrayList<>(res.size());

        FirstDate.add(formatter.parse(splitted[10]); //метод внутри цикла
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для преобразования строки вида `20201225` в дату нужен формат "yyyyMMdd":
`SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");`